# Obtener ruta para descargar archivo pdf en laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-8

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 8. Necesito poder obtener la ruta correcta para descargar una serie de archivos pdf que previamente he almacenado en el repositorio de Laravel pero no consigo obtener la ruta válida.

Esta es mi función:

```
public function getListDocuments($id) {
    $id_client = $id;
    $client_directories = Storage::directories('nominas_' . $id_client);
    $client_tree = [];

    foreach ($client_directories as $directories) {
        /* Obtenemos listados de directorios por cliente */
        $list_directories = explode('/', $directories);
        $directory = end($list_directories);
        /* Obtenemos listado archivos por cliente */
        $client_files = Storage::files($directories);
        $url = Storage::path($directory);

        foreach ($client_files as $files) {
            $file_import = explode('/', $files);
            $file_name = end($file_import);
            $url_file = $url . '/' . $file_name;
            
            $client_tree[$directory][] = [
                'filename' => $file_name,
                'url' => $url_file
            ]; 
        }
    }

    return $client_tree;

}
```

Lo que hago es crear un array en el que voy construyendo un árbol según la estructura de carpetas y archivos a descargar con esta apariencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, la ruta que se asigna al archivo a descargar es absoluta del tipo: c:...\storage\app\2022_07/NOM_07_2022.pdf

Alguién me indica como obtener la ruta correcta?

Gracias.

Comment: He comprobado que eliminando la variable $url y modificando la variable $url_file de esta forma {$url_file = Storage::url('app/' . $directories . '/' . $file_name);}, la ruta que obtengo si sería correcta (storage/app/nominas_2/2022_07/NOM_07_2022.pdf), sin embargo obtengo el error de página no encontrada.

Comment: Corriste el comando "php artisan storage:link" para crear un link simbolico para que se pueda acceder desde el directorio public, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Hola Javier. Si tengo el enlace simbolico creado pero los documentos no los tengo dentro del directorio public, ya que de lo contrario podría acceder a ellos cualquiera. Los archivos se ubican en /storage/app/.... La ruta que sale actualmente en el archivo para descarga es correcta pero sin embargo me lanza el error 404.

Comment: Claro, el link simbolico es justamente para eso, es como un acceso directo al directorio storage, porque no se sube nada en el public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo la solución a mi pregunta para que aquel que le surga el mismo problema pueda solucionarlo.

En el controlador, he modificado la función de forma que asigno como url la ruta completa del fichero sustituyendo la barra invertida por un guión

```
public function getListDocuments($date) {
    $cif = $date;
    $client_directories = Storage::directories($cif);
    $client_tree = [];

    foreach ($client_directories as $directories) {
        /* List directories clients */
        $list_directories = explode('/', $directories);
        $directory = end($list_directories);
        /* List files clients to process*/
        $client_files = Storage::files($directories . '/processed');
        
        foreach ($client_files as $file) {
            $file_import = explode('/', $file);
            $file_name = end($file_import);

            $client_tree[$directory][] = [
                'filename' => $file_name,
                'url' => str_replace('/', '-', $file )
            ];
        }
    }

    return $client_tree;
}
```

He creado una nueva función que recibirá la url del fichero modificad y en la que sustituyo el guión por la barra para que sea correcta.

```
public function download($file) {
    $url = storage_path('app/'.str_replace('-', '/', $file));
    return response()->download($url);
}
```

Indico la ruta que responderá a la llamada desde la vista y que recibirá la ruta completa del archivo incluido el nombre del mismo.

```
Route::get('admin/download/{file}', [ListController::class, 'download'])->name('admin.download.file');
```

Por último, asigno la ruta en la vista

```
<a href="{{route('admin.download.file', ['file' => $key['url']])}}" target="_blank">{{$key['filename']}}</a>
```

Un saludo.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Intente realizar la siguiente función

donde la URL es la ruta completa , el problema es la ruta de arboles
donde si ingresa

/01/cuenta.pdf puede ingresa bien

pero si ingresa

/01/02/03/cuenta.pdf la pagina va a ingresa error 404

por el cual deber ingresa muchas url

```
 <a href="/FilesStorageV3/programacion/Descagar?url=1-COR-IZ-16725%2Fcuenta%20de%20cobro%20junio%20.pdf" 
target="_blank" >
cuenta de cobro junio .pdf 
</a>
```

en el web.php publique la siguiente ruta

```
Route::get('FilesStorageV3/{programacion}/Descagar', 'FilesStoragev3Controller@Descagar');
```

controlador.php

```
public function Descagar(Request $request, $programacion)
    {
        //$request->get("url");

        return Storage::disk($programacion)->download($request->get("url"));
    }
```

para la parte de controlador copie la parte de la siguiente función que siempre utilizo, espero que le hayas funcionado

```
  public function index(Request $request, $model_controller, $ruta = '/')
    {

        $tree_array = [];
        $dir = [];
        $consulta_data = $request->get("consulta_data");
        $ruta = $consulta_url = $request->get("consulta_url");

        if ($ruta == 'null') {
            $ruta = '';
        }

        if ($consulta_data == '') {
            $directorio = Storage::disk($model_controller)->directories($ruta);
            foreach ($directorio as $key => $value) {
                $archivo = explode('/', $value);
                array_push($dir, array(
                    'Dir' => true,
                    'url' => $value,
                    'peso' => Storage::disk($model_controller)->size($value),
                    'modificado' => Storage::disk($model_controller)->lastModified($value),
                    'extension' => 'folder',
                    'archivo' => end($archivo),
                    'check' => false,
                    'estado' => $this->validadVisibilidad($value)

                ));
            }
            $files = Storage::disk($model_controller)->files($ruta);
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $extension = explode('.', $value);
                $archivo = explode('/', $value);
                array_push(
                    $dir,
                    array(
                        'Dir' => false,
                        'url' => $value,
                        'extension' => end($extension),
                        'peso' =>  Storage::disk($model_controller)->size($value),
                        'modificado' => Storage::disk($model_controller)->lastModified($value),
                        'archivo' => end($archivo),
                        'check' => false,
                        'estado' => $this->validadVisibilidad($value)
                    )
                );
            }
        } else {


            $directorio = Storage::disk($model_controller)->allDirectories($ruta);
            foreach ($directorio as $key => $value) {
                if (strpos(strtolower($value), strtolower($consulta_data))) {
                    array_push($dir, array(
                        'Dir' => true,
                        'url' => $value,
                        'peso' => Storage::disk($model_controller)->size($value),
                        'modificado' => Storage::disk($model_controller)->lastModified($value),
                        'extension' => 'folder',
                        'archivo' =>  $value,
                        'check' => false,
                        'estado' => $this->validadVisibilidad($value)
                    ));
                }
            }
            $files = Storage::disk($model_controller)->allFiles($ruta);
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                if (strpos(strtolower($value), strtolower($consulta_data))) {
                    $extension = explode('.', $value);
                    array_push(
                        $dir,
                        array(
                            'Dir' => false,
                            'url' => $value,
                            'extension' => end($extension),
                            'peso' =>  Storage::disk($model_controller)->size($value),
                            'modificado' => Storage::disk($model_controller)->lastModified($value),
                            'archivo' => $value,
                            'check' => false,
                            'estado' => $this->validadVisibilidad($value)
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }




        $w = explode('/', $ruta);
        $di = '';
        $ur = [];
        foreach ($w as $key => $value) {
            $di =  $di . '' . $value . '/';
            array_push(
                $ur,
                array(
                    'nombre' => $value,
                    'url' => $di
                )
            );
        }

        if (count($dir) == 0) {
            array_push($dir, array(
                'Dir' => false,
                'url' => '',
                'peso' => '',
                'modificado' => '',
                'extension' => 'undefined',
                'archivo' => 'Sin Archivos',
                'check' => false
            ));
        }

        $datos = [
            'dir' => $dir,
            'url_dir' => $ur,
            'url_ruta_completa' => $di,

        ];
        return response()->json($datos);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, gracias por tu ayuda pero sinceramente no entiendo el planteamiento que me indicas. Mi problema es que a pesar de mostrar las url de descarga de forma correcta y existir los archivos me indica un erro 404.